# GCD: Making Sequential Download Calls; ONE BY ONE

Tags: ios, multithreading, download, sequential

**SCENARIO**

The app downloads user subscriptions one by one. This call will be made in multiple places (in completion block after another network call and from a button press from a `UIAlertController`). The logic is to download all the subscriptions and once one subscription download is down it goes to the next until all have been downloaded and then our `SVProgressHUD` dismisses. The code works great when we build and run from Xcode. But when we build the IPA and send to our customer, this logic creates some sort of a stall, and the `SVProgressHUD` alert keeps spinning:

[image]

This is a big problem because our application is focused around downloading content from subscriptions.

Why is this logic stalling after I Archive and build an IPA from it, but **not** when I build and run from Xcode?

Code Below:

```
// Making the call 

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        DGWebService().syncUserSubscribedContent {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.finishLogin()
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
// Sequentially going through each subscription and downloading them

    func syncUserSubscribedContent(completion: @escaping Constants.WebService.ContentCompletion) {
        let subscriptions = MPTUser.sharedUser.getSubscriptionsForDownload()
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            if subscriptions.count > 0 {
                var index:Int = 0
                var t = subscriptions.count
                var downloading: Bool = false
                while t != 0 {
                    if downloading == false {
                        downloading = true
                        if index < 0 {
                            index = 0
                        }
                        if index > subscriptions.count - 1 {
                            index = subscriptions.count - 1
                        }
                        if index <= subscriptions.count {
                            let subscription = subscriptions[index]
                            if subscription.didDownloadContent == false {
                                if let subscriptionID = subscription.subscriptionID {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Downloading Documents\nfor\n\(subscription.functionalGroupName!)\n\(index+1) of \(subscriptions.count)")
                                    }
                                    self.getUserSubscribedContent(subscriptionID: subscriptionID, completion: { (success) in
                                        subscription.didDownloadContent = true
                                        index += 1
                                        t -= 1
                                        downloading = false
                                    })
                                }
                                else {
                                    index += 1
                                    t -= 1
                                    downloading = false
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            index += 1
                            t -= 1
                            downloading = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            completion()
        }
    }
```

---

`self.getUserSubscribedContent` is a function that downloads the content and sends a completion back in the block.

If someone could help me out here it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have a lot of repeated code in your example. Have you tried looking at running a `DispatchGroup` on a background thread (which will make your downloads synchronous), and updating the label on the main thread after each download?

Comment: Hello @ILikeTau. That is a promising sounding suggestion. If you could give me an example in code it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a `DispatchGroup`. Here's a rough (and untested) example:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let subscriptions = MPTUser.sharedUser.getSubscriptionsForDownload()
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    var completed = 0
    let completion: (Bool) -> Void = {
        if $0 {
            completed += 1
        }
        group.leave()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Downloading Documents\nfor\n\(subscription.functionalGroupName!)\n\(completed) of \(subscriptions.count)")
        }
    }
    for subscription in subscriptions {
        self.getUserSubscribedContent(subscriptionID: subscription.subscriptionID, completion: completion)
        group.enter()
    }
    // However long you want to wait (in seconds) before timing out
    _ = group.wait(timeout: .now() + 30)
}
```